# Am I allowed to publish reviews submitted for courses in open-access journals?

Tags: publications, intellectual-property, review-articles

Question is rather self explanatory.

I understand that the article was submitted within the context of a course within the university, but it is nonetheless my intellectual property. I also generally cannot seem to get a clear answer from the university's staff.

**Generally, is it acceptable and legal to submit an article or review submitted within the context of a course to a journal for publication?**

Comment: Does it really make any difference to your question whether the journal is open-access?

Answer (score 5):

I cannot see anything in general that could prevent you from submitting a report written in a course to a journal. There are of course several issues you need to be aware of. First, did you do the entire work yourself from coming up with the idea through researching the topic and writing? You need to look if someone else's "intellectual property" is involved. Second, you do not state under what circumstances your report was written. Submitting a manuscript to a journal involves meeting certain standards so under what I would consider normal circumstances, course reports would not be in shape for publication. One obvious reason for this is that reviews typically involves reading and summarizing/synthesizing a very large number of papers, work that cannot fit into the short time span of a course. So, in general, I doubt the scenario you describe would work without significant extra work. I have no doubts the core of a useful paper can be achieved within a course format but from there to publication is a different story. So without additional details, it is difficult to assess the likely success but the principle stands, yes it is acceptable and legal as long as the work adheres to general publication ethics.

Comment: Thanks Peter, you raise some great points. I would in fact spend much more time on the paper to make it up to par for journal publication, but you've made me question whether the professor of the course would indeed be a contributing author.

Comment: Normally, the professor would not be an author, otherwise, they could not give you a grade for your individual effort--coursework normally assumes that the students who receive the grade did the work themselves. The professor might be thanked in the acknowledgements section, but should not normally be considered a coauthor.